# How to compare different data preprocessing when using CNN from sratch

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, image-processing, data-preprocessing

Let's says you use a CNN for image classification. You have binary images: pixel values = 0 or 1.

Some tools can be used to get those images with continuous values (i'll not explain how  since that not the purpose of the post).

You don't know which encoding format is best.

Now you build a CNN from scratch, so you'll optimise you'r CNN on one image format (you decided to build it using binary images). So you'r model will **very likely**  be better on binary image since it's has been build on this format

The only way to know if using continuous value can be better than binary value is to create a new CNN from scratch, using different hyperparameter or architecture?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you always retrain your model from your initial configuration if you change hyperparameters or preprocessing.

Btw the preprocessing steps might also be viewed as data augmentation. In this case you could add both types to your model and train on both to increase variation in your training data.

Comment: i'm interested about using both: binary image and continuous image as training set. isn't it going to biais the future model since, in prediction time, we will only use one format of images?